# How to open designer view in GUI builder in IntelliJIDEA

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea

I've started learning building GUI with GUI designer in IntelliJ. When i am creating new form everything is ok and i have a view like 
[this: 
[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zFPE.png)

But when I save the file, exit IntelliJ and then open it again it looks like 
[this: 
[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpcyi.png)

I have no idea how to switch to designer view like on the first screenshot. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 0):

Actually,if you read the IntelliJ Idea docs,it is written that you cannot edit the GUI in XML mode,so the sole way to have something like this is most probably via a plugin.The nearest you can go without plugins is to go to the structure tab on left side and see the structure of the form.

Comment: Could you add a link to that docs sections?